# Reactjs get data with async on componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I trying to do is, get user data before render, I made a object call API, it get data from api with axios (it get successfull) now I want to get it on info.js compontent, so I call it on componentDidMount:

**API.js**

```
const API = {
  async getUser() {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const token = cookies.get('token');
    let result = null;

    if (token) {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/user').then(res => {
        if (res.data.success) {
          result = res.data.success;
        }
      });
      return await result;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

**Info.js**

```
import API from 'API'

export default class UserInfo extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {result: null};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let result = API.getUser();
        this.setState({
            result: result
        });
        console.log(result)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="UserInfo">
                {this.state.result}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But it give me this:

```
Promise {<pending>}...
```

So I confused, what I have done wrong?

Comment: Return the result, no need to await anymore in you API.js

Comment: @NickyPrabowo No, when I remove await, it return `null`

Comment: Ok, then Promise pending means you need to add `then` in your result in info.js.

Comment: @NickyPrabowo can you provide an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   async componentDidMount() {
        let result = await API.getUser();
        this.setState({
            result: result
        });
        console.log(result)
    }
```

Comment: You don't have any description, but I tried this and it return correctly in `console.log` but when I want to render it `<div className="UserInfo">              {this.state.result.name}
            </div>` it give me error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
` while it working in `console.log(this.state.result.name)`

Comment: could you change componentDidMount to componentWillMount and try again please?

Comment: componentDidMount is called after the first Render, so you're getting that issue, I think.

Comment: No @JikunL, he is getting the issue as in the first render the state of `result` is `null` and he is trying to reference `name` out of it which for sure is an error .. poor debugging skills. I fixed it in my comment

Comment: I figured out somehow.. at first it return `null` so it give me that error, after few seconds it give me right data, so I fixed issue with `{this.state.result != null ? this.state.result.name : null}` so can I avoid to return `null` ?

Comment: Hi @tourtravel, it's better you change it to just use `&&` or change the result initial state to `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Probably this should fix it for you!

```
import API from 'API'

export default class UserInfo extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { result: undefined };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let result = await API.getUser();
        this.setState({ result });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="UserInfo">
                {this.state.result && this.state.result.name}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because setState is asynchronous. Try it like this and you will get the result you expect:

```
this.setState({
  result: result
}, () => console.log(result);
```

If you use this [reactjs.org page](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) there is a bit about it further down (search for callback).

Comment: Nothing changed, still nothing return. Also I return `result` not `this.state.result`, so it doesn't matter setState is asynchronous in this case. I just return normal `let`